# write a function that sorts a list using python

Tags: python

Python:

> write a function that accepts a list of numbers.
> call the function: sort_the_list().
> sort them by removing the miminum, one at a time.
> the results will be stored in a temporary list
> and return the new list

my function is returning just the minimum value, and i expected it to return the empty_list with the numbers in order

```
def sort_the_list(list_nums):
    empty_list = []
    min_val = list_nums[0]
    for ndx in range(0,len(list_nums)):
        if min_val > list_nums[ndx]:
            min_val = list_nums[ndx]
            empty_list.append(min_val)
    return empty_list       
    
def main(): 
    list_nums = [18, -3, 0]
    sorted_list_nums = sort_by_min_removal(list_nums)
    print("the sorted list is: ", sorted_list_nums)

main()
```

Comment: Get out of the habit of using `for index in range(len(list)):`. Use `for item in list:`

Comment: If you follow the logic of your function, it goes over the list just once, adding values to the end as it finds values smaller than the most recent one it found. Try your function with a few different inputs and you'll find that it doesn't do what you expect at all. For example, call it with `[3,2,1]` and `[0, 3, 2, 1]`

Comment: You can use the `min()` function to find the minimum element of a list.

Comment: What is wrong with your code?

Comment: @Barmar - clearly, the point is for OP to write a function that does it 'by hand', likely homework. @ PCM, try running it and you'll find there's several issues with it.

Comment: Learn to use the while statement to loop until your input list is empty, and as you pull the minimum off the original list and add it to the sorted list, you should also remove it from the input list.

Comment: @Grismar, I know that, but shouldn't OP include what the error or unexpected output is, in the question?

Answer (score 0):

The instructions say to remove the smallest element from the list and add it to the result, and keep repeating this. You never remove anything, and you never repeat it. You just go through the list once, appending an element whenever it's smaller than the previous minimum so far.

```
def sort_the_list(list_nums):
    result_list = []
    while len(list_nums) > 0:
        smallest = min(list_nums)
        result_list.append(smallest)
        list_nums.remove(smallest)
    return result_list
```